# I want to put a JS function that applies to all the elements of a list but I can't copy it into each element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list filled with HTML elements and I want every element in the list to change color when the mouse is over the element using the "onmouseover" javascript function. I want to know if there is a way to make a function that changes every element without copying and pasting into every element of the list.

Sorry for my bad English and thank you for your answers.

Comment: use a common class for the elements and using that class you can do that

Comment: You can use a `className:hover` CSS rule to make this work automatically without any javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Yes use CSS hover is another way. You can write your own javascript to do so like  this.

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
function test(id){
  var elm = document.getElementById(id);  
  var i=0;
  while(elm.children[i]!=null){
  elm.children[i].onclick=function(){
    this.style.backgroundColor="red";
    // do what you want to do to element here
  };
   i++; 
  }
}
</script>

<ul id ='testId' onclick="test(this.id)" >
<li> text1 </li>
<li> text1 </li>
<li> text1 </li>
</ul> `
```